# How do you keep unity desktop in a remote desktop connection

Tags: networking, unity, remote-desktop

I am looking to set up a remote desktop PC. But from what i had read, the half to install another form of desktop interface that is not unity, these are utility's like XRDP, X2go. I am wondering if there is a remote desktop utility that will keep unity (the 3d version) and allow me to access the desktop remotely. The connection will be done wireless vita a desktop WI-fi expansion card over a WLAN network. If the client PC half to have Ubuntu installed, i will install it. (FYI, this connection will also stream games, virtual boxes, and so on)

Answer (score 1):

To be able to access Unity Desktop via XRDP Software on a Ubuntu 16.04 machine, you need to perform the following actions

1. Install TigerVNC
2. Install XRDP
3. Configure system to use the Unity Desktop during XRDP sessions

Full instructions can be found [at this location](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=9962)

Comment: Griffon is the author of this posts/solution